# Undo closed tabs for Safari

Tags: browser-addons, safari

I have tried to find a way to undo closed tabs, which is a basic feature of Firefox and Chrome with no luck.

In Safari on a Mac, there is History » Reopen Last Closed Window (and also Reopen All Windows from Last Session), but there seems to be no such function for the last tab. (And unlike Firefox, it does not restore any text one might already have typed on the web page, but often Safari is smart enough to warn *"You have entered text on “[..]”. If you close the window, your changes will be lost."*)

Any suggestions?

Comment: there was nothing like undo in firefox in safari just can go in your history and open it again.

Comment: Given the Reopen Last Closed Window, this calls for using Safari » Report Bugs to Apple...

Comment: @Am1rr3zA: firefox does have an undo: CTRL+SHIFT+F5

Answer (score 4):

This was added in Safari 5. (<kbd>⌘Z</kbd> or *Edit ▸ Undo Close Tab*.)

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to go into the history menu and dig for the page you're looking for (shouldn't be too hard; it'll probably be near the top).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) you could emulate this behaviour. I did an initial run at it. Thats the [gist](https://gist.github.com/wrtsprt/10180606) of it.